# How to reference a widget inside a specific tab of a QTabWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtabwidget

I am using PyQt to make a GUI for a circuit simulator, and am programmatically creating and deleting tabs (i.e. the user clicks on a button, and a new tab is added to a QTabWidget).

This is already working (I drew a QFrame in Qt Creator and, in my code, add it as a new tab), but I need to refer to a widget which is inside a specific tab (e.g. a QwtPlot inside the 3rd tab). How can this be achieved?

Comment: Maybe [`QTabWidget.widget(index)`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#widget)?

Comment: @reclosedev - That should be the answer

Comment: @reclosedev That did it, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the widget from a specific tab by calling [`QTabWidget.widget(index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#widget).