# PyQT - referencing a widget within a specific tab

Tags: python, qt, tabs

For example, I want a button in a tab to clear a textEdit box in that tab, (I know I can do this directly but I want to know how to get back to the widget from the function) but I can't figure out how to reference the textEdit:

(indentation is messed up here but fine at my end)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class CC(QtGui.QWidget):

   def __init__(self):
        super(CC, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        tab_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)

        ################## tab1
        tab1 = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(tab1)
        ###### add widgets to layout

        clear = QtGui.QPushButton('clear results box', tab1)
        clear.resize(clear.sizeHint())
        clear.move(50, 50)
        clear.clicked.connect(self.clearit)

        results = QtGui.QTextEdit(tab1)
        results.move(250, 50)
        results.setFixedWidth(450)
        results.setFixedHeight(350)
        ######################

        tab_widget.addTab(tab1, "Tab 1")

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(tab_widget)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 500)
        self.setFixedSize(800, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Crouton MN Toolw v05')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('drk.ico'))        

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)    

        self.show()

    def clearit(self):
        tab1.results.clear()   ##### <<< here is what doesn't work, please help :)
        #self.results.clear()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = CC()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried self.results.clear(), tab_widget.results.clear(), tab1.results.clear() and about a dozen other variations but no joy, I am missing something obvious. (Like a brain maybe.)

I have found this answer but I am too stupid to grasp what exactly I should do:
[How to reference a widget inside a specific tab of a QTabWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449708/how-to-reference-a-widget-inside-a-specific-tab-of-a-qtabwidget)

Any help appreciated!

edit: I can get it to work by sticking 'global results' inside initUI and calling 'results.clear()' from the function but there is surely a more correct way?

Answer (score 0):

First, does your tab layout stuff actually work? I know there are different ways of doing this, but you never specifically set the layout on your `tab1` widget. I would do this:

```
tab1 = QtGui.QWidget()
layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
tab1.setLayout(layout)
```

Second, the link you referenced is talking about getting the individual tab widget from the `QTabWidget`. In your case this would be getting `tab1` from `tab_widget`.

Third, in your `clearit` function you can't reference any old variable from the `initUI` function. If you aren't familiar with python variable scope you may want to look it up. Anything you reference from the `clearit` function either has to be a global (usually unnecessary or bad practice) or has to be passed as an argument. Since `QWidgets` are objects you are provided a reference to the object instance itself, `self`. So you could do something like this to get a reference to the `results` object (not tested):

```
results = self.layout.children()[0].widget(0).layout.children()[1]
results.clear()
```

There are other ways to get children, but bottom line is you are traversing a series of layouts and widgets to get to an object. The easiest solution (which may be the "direct" method as you call it) is to put this in your `initUI` function after working with the `results` object:

```
self.results = results
```

Then in the `clearit` function:

```
self.results.clear()
```

If there are more "Qt" ways of doing this, let me know. I consider this the "pythonic" way to do it, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: Thank you, that's cleared up a few things for me. For the moment though I'm just making the few things that I have to global as it's simple and it works. :)

Comment: Ok...but assigning to self is probably more clear and more correct and in my opinion easier than setting a global.